# Find the 10 most frequently occurring words with morphology

Tags: python, text-mining, text-analysis

Please tell me how to solve this problem better.

I have the text of the Russian and I want to find the 10 most common words **with morphology**.
Maybe there is any open source libraries to solve this issue in **python**?

Comment: You're looking for [stemming](https://www.google.com/search?q=russian+stemmer+python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of Python morphology analyzers for Russian to normalize the word:

- https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2
- https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy
- https://github.com/irokez/Pyrus

There is also a Porter stemmer for Russian in https://github.com/nltk/nltk. Also, you could employ http://company.yandex.ru/technologies/mystem/ from a command line.

I'd recommend pymorphy2 for your task, but I'm a bit biased :)

Answer (score 2):

[PyStemmer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyStemmer/) and [NLTK](http://nltk.org/) are the two obvious libraries here.